# Will this work? Transistor to keep the uC power supply on once a trigger happens

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, transistors, batteries

[image: Transistor to Keep uC Power ON]

I am trying to have a switch (momentary) on a remote, that will send power to the LDO.
But as the switch is momentary, the power will be disconnected.

Can I have a transistor or some Mosfet to keep the power on, via the microcontroller pin,
once the microcontroller is powered on.

This way the microcontroller can cut the power once done, and whenever the button is pressed,
the microcontroller can keep the power on, until work done, or another button is pressed.

Is there any example circuit for the same, or any better way. On/Off switch is not possible, due to design constraints.

Comment: Question - What state will "uC 3.3V pin" be when the power is disconnected.   Will it be able to pass a trickle of current???  Would be problematic if that happened.  I'm thinking micro-amps to nano-amps could turn that transistor on enough to cause issues.

Comment: Add --- BTW, you drew this with an NPN transistor.   You need to use a PNP in a "pass transistor" role such at this....

Comment: When the microcontroller is switched off, the uC 3.3v pin would be low, I guess GND or floating.

Comment: How to use a PNP transistor here, I didn't understand

Comment: When the microcontroller has no power applied, you really can not know what it will do.  Rarely would that be listed in a datasheet   .......    This is how a PNP is used in a pass configuration:    https://2n3904blog.com/low-noise-high-psrr-ldo-series-pass-element/      ...  I have a known-good circuit that will do what you want, but it's quite a bit more complex than what you show above.  I didn't design it, it's in a product we did a few years ago.  I would send you the snippet of the schematic if nobody has something better for you.

Comment: That's was my idea, didn't know what to search, so just created a dummy sketch. This is not an actual circuit, looking for better actual circuits. Now I know, its called with multiple names: auto power off circuit, latching power circuit, soft touch switch. Found a circuit on internet: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/latching-power-switch-circuit-auto-power-off-circuit-esp32-esp8266-arduino/, I think this is what I am looking for. Or may be anything much easier than that, I don't think I need a 24Amps mosfet, need a find the cheapest mosfet or another simple circuit.

Comment: @PriyankBolia When you write "remote" do you mean like a TV remote? Or do you mean a switch with long wires? Or? And are you only unpowering an LDO, but the MCU controlling the LDO stays on, itself? Or is this the case that the LDO supplies the power that the MCU uses and that when the MCU turns it off, the MCU itself also goes off?

Comment: @PriyankBolia Also, how precise is your energy/power usage details? Can you accept that when the MCU wants to unpower the LDO that this happens "a little later" (say, 100 ms later or 1 s later or... etc?) Or are things such that it must be coincident (within a very short time) that the LDO is off when the MCU says so?

Comment: I mean TV remote, the LDO is powering the MCU, so when the LDO is cut off, the MCU is turned down automatically, and the transistor base will be low or floating I guess.

Comment: Its doesn't matter 100ms, basically its a TV remote, so I want long battery life from a single A23 12V battery. The MCU will be anyway shut down after some time, once the LDO is cut off, due to capacitors on its own power rail.

Comment: @PriyankBolia So, when you press a button (would this be *any* button?) the circuit is to become powered up and to stay up for as long as the MCU decides that there's no need to continue? I'd use a "keep-alive" circuit for this -- a BJT and a MOSFET and a few diodes. Your MCU would periodically pulse the circuit to keep it active. When the MCU is done, it just stops pulsing and the power is then withdrawn shortly later on. It's safer this way. If the MCU fails to pulse the circuit, it will be shut down. I like that method lots better. So, would that be about it?

Comment: normal SMD 6x6x6 tactile switch, yes, the circuit would power on and stay until another off button is pressed. Can you explain in detail, I am basically from s/w side, my understanding much about BJT, etc. is not great.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is good, but:

1. For high side switch use PNP (or P-chan) driven with NPN. With your design you will push to LDO 2.6V only.
2. The button press must be longer then **LDO start-up time + charging filters time + boot time of MCU + time to set pin high**. Set MCU fuse to startup as fast as possible and place *setPinHigh()* code very close to beginning can help you.

[image]

Comment: Actually point 2 is not an issue, as I want to hold the switch for some duration to turn on, to avoid accidental start, as it will be used by kids. So don't need touch to start.

Comment: Can I add another button, between the R3 and Q1 connected to GND, to turn of the device. I don't want to waste a microcontroller pin. As this is embedded device, nothing to save, hard shutdown should not be a problem.

Comment: Place the turn-off button between Q1 base and GND is a good aproach, but think about how long will MCU live from capacitor filters. In sleep mode it can be even many minutes, depends on sum of load. Also MCU hard reset/turn-off can  lead to program malfunction, so you must count with the "reset can come anytime" when you write a code.

Comment: Btw, for turn-on button there is a better place than bridge Mosfet. Bridge Q1 from collector to emitter rather. Or even better sulution is from Vin to Q1 base - that however needs additional curcuitry to protect MCU_pin from overvoltage.

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/randomnerdtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/latch-power-circuit-how-it-works-2-1.png I go with this design, as this is what you are saying, the additional circuitry is just pair of diodes.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, it won't work out.

An easy way to achieve this:

1. Build a *latch* out of (typically two) transistors that you latch on with your button
2. Turn off the latch using your microcontroller and a third transistor, typically.
3. (optional, but strongly recommended) don't try to feed your regulator through your transistors. Instead, buy a regulator with an "enable" pin. Then, the regulator can be part of the latching itself.

Comment: Can you explain with a circuit, about the 2 transistor method, and also can recommend a suitable part with enable pin, that is almost same price as good old AMS1117